# Chrome OS local link stopped working

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-drive, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I've created a very simple webpage as a test on my chromebook. I have an index.html and a test.txt file within the same folder. I have linked the test.txt with the html `<a href="test.txt">`. Whenever I view the index page in chrome and click on the link it takes me to an `about:blank` page.

This is especially odd because previously my other site, which had multiple links to files in a folder stored on google drive, worked as it should. However, now it is also returning `about:blank` pages when the links are clicked and I can't right click or ctrl-click to open in a new tab.

I have tried clearing browsing data and disabling extensions, to no avail. I tested it on my desktop, which is running windows with google drive installed, and the pages are working as they should. So, it seems this only on my chromebook.

I have also put the files in the downloads folder of my chromebook, which made the site function properly. It seems as if the functionality was suddenly dropped from google drive, but nothing has changed as far as I know.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated as I can't seem to find anything related to my problem online.

Answer (score 0):

Open google drive on the web and over-write the files with your working local files.

Comment: Google drive files ARE local files on the chromebook. It's treated like an actual drive. The working files in my Windows drive folder are the same files on my chromebook.

Comment: I am thinking sync issues.  Over-write eliminates that issue.

Comment: Good point, unfortunately I just tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: I'm sorry, if you view source from both platforms and they are the same, it is beyond my meager abilities.